# Want to pass empty string in datetime field in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am passing empty value in json payload in datetime field. Below is json payload example.

Here in dateOf in Loans2021 I am passing ""

```
{
    "isCompany": null,
    "Loans2020": {
        "dateOf": "2022-12-31T19:00:00.000Z",
        "Amount": 1000,
    },
    "Loans2021": {
        "Amount": 0,
        "dateOf": ""
    }
}
```

I am getting error as per below.

```
"errors": {
    "request": [
      "The request field is required."
    ],
    "$.Loans2021.dateOn": [
      "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]. Path:.."
    ]
```

I want to pass empty string in datetime field so any idea how to do this.

I am using C#, .net core in web api

Comment: well, what are you trying to _achieve_ by posting `""`? if you want the value of the deserialised object to be `null` - have you tried posting `null`?

Comment: I tried with null and it is working fine with that.. but my front end developer is telling he want to pass empty string

Comment: But empty string is a string. It's not NULL or DATETIME. Tell them no, they need to pass correct data.

Comment: @Sam then tell your front end developer he should just _do it the right way_ instead of the stupid way. the best practice to represent `null` is to use `null`, not an empty string.

Comment: You can add a check, when the date variable comes with "", you will assign null to that date variable as null. If null works for you, I thing this solution will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass the dateOf in this "" format instead of this pass the dateOf as null.

Try like this

```
{
"isCompany": null,
"Loans2020": {
    "dateOf": "2022-12-31T19:00:00.000Z",
    "Amount": 1000,
},
"Loans2021": {
    "Amount": 0,
    "dateOf": null
}
```

But Before this set your dateOf property as nullable in your entity class

```
public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to pass a string to an object of type `DateTime`.
Try to implement a custom json converter.

In your C# property, add the declaration:

```
[JsonPropertyName("dateOf")]
[JsonConverter(typeof(stringToDateTimeConverter))]
public DateTime? date;
```

Here is an example:

```
public sealed class StringToDateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<double>
{
    public override double Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert, 
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        DateTime.TryParse(reader.GetString(),out DateTime value);
        return value;
    }

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        double value, 
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```